# CoreData not Persisting?

Tags: swift, core-data

I am saving an exercise into core data and calling it into the table, this works in terms of carrying the info from the user input into the table, however the coredata doesnt persist so when i re open the app, the entry is lost.

It was actually working yesterday and seems to have broken, but I havent made a change that would effect this as far as im aware. The one thing i found when debugging is that when I loaded the app its meant to point at the sql database in my console, however its changed to a .configurationprofiles file? Could this be a cause and what would the fix be? I will include the code for the tableview and the code for the user entry form below to show the information flow. Let me know if any other data is needed to be added.

[image]

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ExerciseEditorController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext?

    var userRepsCount = Int()
    var userSetsCount = Int()

    @IBOutlet weak var userExerciseName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var userExerciseSetCounter: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var userExerciseRepsCounter: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var userExerciseWeight: UITextField!

    @IBAction func userSetsStepper(_ sender: UIStepper) {
        userExerciseSetCounter.text = Int(sender.value).description
        self.userSetsCount = Int(sender.value)
    }

    @IBAction func userRepsStepper(_ sender: UIStepper) {
        userExerciseRepsCounter.text = Int(sender.value).description
        self.userRepsCount = Int(sender.value)
    }

    @IBAction func cancelExerciseEditor(_ sender: Any) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToWorkoutDesignerWithSegue:", sender: self)
    }

    @IBAction func saveExerciseToWorkout(_ sender: Any) {

        createExercise()
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToWorkoutDesignerWithSegue:", sender: self)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = (UIColor.customBackgroundGraphite())

        userExerciseSetCounter.text = String(userSetsCount)
        userExerciseRepsCounter.text = String(userSetsCount)
        userExerciseWeight.delegate = self
        userExerciseWeight.keyboardType = .numbersAndPunctuation

    }

    func createExercise() {
        let userExerciseWeightSet = Double(self.userExerciseWeight.text!) //make this safe!

        guard let managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext else { return }

        let userExercise = UserExercise(context: managedObjectContext)

        userExercise.name = userExerciseName.text
        userExercise.sets = Int64(userSetsCount)
        userExercise.reps = Int64(userRepsCount)
        userExercise.weight = userExerciseWeightSet! //make this safe!
        userExercise.createdAt = Date().timeIntervalSince1970

    }

    func animateTextField(textField: UITextField, up: Bool) {
        let movementDistance:CGFloat = -130
        let movementDuration: Double = 0.3
        var movement:CGFloat = 0
        if up {
            movement = movementDistance
        }
        else {
            movement = -movementDistance
        }

        UIView.beginAnimations("animateTextField", context: nil)
        UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
        UIView.setAnimationDuration(movementDuration)
        self.view.frame = self.view.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: movement)
        UIView.commitAnimations()
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        self.animateTextField(textField: textField, up:true)
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        self.animateTextField(textField: textField, up:false)
    }

}
```

And this is the tableview:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreData

class WorkoutDesignerController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    @IBAction func unwindToWorkoutDesigner(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {}
    @IBOutlet weak var workoutDesignerTable: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tapToAddExercise: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicatorView: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    @IBAction func cancelWorkoutDesigner(_ sender: Any) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToTemplatesWithSegue", sender: self)
    }

    private let persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Lift")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupView()
        workoutDesignerTable.delegate = self
        workoutDesignerTable.dataSource = self

        view.backgroundColor = (UIColor.customBackgroundGraphite())

        persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores { (persistentStoreDescription, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Unable to Load Persistent Store")
                print("\(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")

            } else {
                self.setupView()

                do {
                    try self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
                } catch {
                    let fetchError = error as NSError
                    print("Unable to Perform Fetch Request")
                    print("\(fetchError), \(fetchError.localizedDescription)")
                }

                self.updateView()
            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        guard let userExercises = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects else { return 0 }
        return userExercises.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? RoutineTableViewCell else {
            fatalError("Unexpected Index Path")
        }

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.customBackgroundGraphite()
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white

        let userExercise = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)

        cell.nameLabel.text = userExercise.name
        cell.repsLabel.text = String(userExercise.reps)
        cell.setsLabel.text = String(userExercise.sets)
        cell.weightLabel.text = String(userExercise.weight)

        return cell
    }

    private func setupView() {
        setupMessageLabel()
        updateView()
    }

    private func setupMessageLabel() {
        tapToAddExercise.text = "Tap + To Add An Exercise To The Routine"
    }

    fileprivate func updateView() {
        var hasUserExercises = false
        if let UserExercise = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects {
            hasUserExercises = UserExercise.count > 0
        }
        workoutDesignerTable.isHidden = !hasUserExercises
        tapToAddExercise.isHidden = hasUserExercises

        activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
    }

    fileprivate lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<UserExercise> = {

        // Create Fetch Request
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<UserExercise> = UserExercise.fetchRequest()

        // Configure Fetch Request
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdAt", ascending: true)]

        // Create Fetched Results Controller
        let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.persistentContainer.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

        // Configure Fetched Results Controller
        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

        return fetchedResultsController
    }()

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "addNewExerciseSegue" {
            if let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? ExerciseEditorController {
                // Configure View Controller
                destinationViewController.managedObjectContext = persistentContainer.viewContext
            }
        }
    }

    func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        workoutDesignerTable.beginUpdates()
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        workoutDesignerTable.endUpdates()

        updateView()
    }

    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
        switch (type) {
        case .insert:
            if let indexPath = newIndexPath {
                workoutDesignerTable.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            }
            break;
        default:
            print("...")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: To make data persistent you have to save the managed object context.

Comment: Is that it what's achieved in the save buttons function saveexercise?

Comment: No, you're creating the instance but you don't save the context. Somewhere you have to call `context.save()`

Comment: this solved it if you want to post i can mark answered otherwise I can delete the post

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `context.save()`.